# How to exit the 'Enter commit message' dialogue in JetBrains/RubyMine VCS

Tags: rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I'm working in the terminal that comes with RubyMine. I did a commit, then got the 'Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary'-dialogue. I entered a commit message, but now I can't seem to exit this dialogue/submit the message.. How do I exit?

Pressing `esc` didn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out `esc` actually does something: it gets you out of text-editing mode and allows new command. It just didn't give any visual feedback.

After pressing `esc` I typed `:wq` and all was well.